# How can I access a user's facebook groups without the api? I have tried to web scrape but facebook server is blocking my requests

Tags: php, facebook, web-scraping

I am trying to get groups that users belong to on facebook. I know that the api allows access to only groups in which the user is the admin, but i have seen some websites that does that. I dont know how they did it but I thought of web scraping. Please, does any body have an idea on how this can be done?

Answer (score 0):

answer is pretty simple you can't access facebook group info without adding your api information... that's why fb can't recognize u and blocking ur request.. so create facebook developer app where you will get api key and secret key... for more info go to `https://developers.facebook.com/`

Comment: I have a facebook app hence an api key and secret key. I know of what the api grants access to; that is /{user-id}/groups api edge which grants access to groups in which the user is an admin. What I want is to get groups that the user belongs to.

Comment: For linkedin api i can access all group activities but m not sure about with facebook api is it possible or not?